# Where is the R.java file in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, aapt

Where is the R.java file in Android Studio?

Comment: All you need to do is type R. to see the autocompletion suggestions.

Answer (score 51):

Based on the [new stable release of Android Studio (3.6)](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/android-studio-36.html) we have:
[image]

So, now to find your generated resource classes you need the following steps:

**1) Open your project.**

**2) Go to your module build path.**

**3) Open the *outputs/apk/debug/app-name-debug.apk* file.**

**4) Choose your classes.dex file.**

**5) Look at the down placed area and go to your full package path.**

**6) You can see all bytecoded resource classes. So, scroll down to what you are looking for.**

[image]

**7) Expand the resource class you need to proceed (for example, let it be R.id)**

[image]

**8) Go to you id's.**

[image]

**That's it.**

**UPDATE:**

If you would like to see actual id integer number you should follows steps below:

**1) By (7) Go to the resource class you need to proceed and right click to show the context menu**

**2) Choose "Show Bytecode" to see the flexible dialog "DEX Byte Code for R$id", for example, for id class**

[image]

**3) Scroll down to the actual id to look its number**

[image]

Comment: That's the correct answear in 2020 (Android Studio 3.6), but how can I read actual id? like button17 = 52444873 ?

Comment: if somebody wonders: "The new Android Gradle Plugin generates the corresponding bytecode directly and does not make the intermediate R.java file."

https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/cant-find-r-java-in-android-studio-3-6-newest-release/17266

Comment: Also look at `classes2.dex` and `classes3.dex` for your package. If you search an `id`, probably you won't find it there, because it can belong to another package. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61277205/2914140 for a short way.

Comment: For me it was `classes2.dex`, and `classes.dex` didn't contain my app package at all

Comment: For me, selecting `resources.arsc` in the APK gave me a table with the type of resource (id, drawable, color, attr, etc) on the left and on the right the ID shown in the Crash and the Name of the resource.

Answer (score 40):

Although the current Android Gradle Plugin doesn't generate a `R.java` anymore you can still inspect the corresponding class file (see Sergey V.`s answer).

However, if you (like probably in most cases) just want to look up the generated IDs for your resources, there is an easier way:

In the project pane on the left hand side switch from *Android* to *Project* view using the drop-down at the top. Then navigate to `app/build/intermediates/runtime_symbol_list/<insert build type here>/R.txt`. This file lists **all IDs generated by AGP** during the build process.

Comment: Thanks! A correct answer. It will look like `int drawable bonus_item 0x7f0800f1`.

Comment: This is the short and corrrect answer

Comment: This directory doesn't exist anymore, however `stable_resource_ids_file` does.

Comment: @MartinZeitler This might depend on the AGP version used or some flag in your build configuration. I've tested with 8.3.0, and I actually see both directories.

Comment: The strange thing is, that [`SingleArtifact.RUNTIME_SYMBOL_LIST`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.3/com/android/build/api/artifact/SingleArtifact.RUNTIME_SYMBOL_LIST) reads: Added in 8.3.1... which kind of contradicts the date of your answer.

Comment: Maybe it just wasn't available as a separate artifact before within AGP. 

Answer (score 18):

I use Android Studio 3.3.2

```
\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\android\support\constraint\R.java
```

[image]

Comment: That's right,thanks so much.BTW,I'm using AS 3.5.2.

Comment: There is no `not_namespaced_r_class_sources` folder in AS 3.6.1

Comment: @gmk57 Look at answer by Sergey V. down here.

Answer (score 17):

As noted above, "The new Android Gradle Plugin generates the corresponding bytecode directly and does not make the intermediate R.java file".

Using the [ubuntudroid solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61277205/2914140) you can find an `id` also this way. Find `R.txt` and copy absolute path. Project > app > build > intermediates > runtime_symbol_list > debug > R.txt. Then right click and select `Copy Path...`, `1. Absolute Path Ctrl+Shift+C`.

[image]

This way you will obtain a path to `R.txt`, for instance, "C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\your_project\app\build\intermediates\runtime_symbol_list\debug\R.txt". Copy the path without `R.txt` to a text file for future references, for example, with Notepad++.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find in directory. Insert an `id` and the path.

[image]

== Old answer ==

Change a project view from `Android` to `Project` or `Project Files`. Find one of these two files.

[image]

Then you can revert back to `Android` view.

Answer (score 13):

[image: //The picture]

I use Android Studio 2.3.3. The `R.java` file is shown in the picture above.

In the left upper side, there is a select list. Select the `[project]` option so that you can see all the folders and files.

Comment: I feel sorry for the OP. I seriously doubt he/she was asking for a screenshot of the actual R file. The answer should clearly explain how it is generated as well.

Comment: There was never a "screenshot of the actual R file" here (whatever that means -- a screenshot of the contents?). There is a screenshot of the R file's location in the directory tree, showing where to find it. This is exactly what the OP asked - "Where is the R file?" not "How is the R file generated?" If you would like an explanation of the latter, feel free to add one, but that's not a defect of this answer.

Comment: The server in which the picture was deployed to has been removed or is no longer valid. This is up to Stackoverflow to restore back the images. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGLud.jpg

Comment: Sorry, my comment was in reply to user2453382's comment. Your picture looks fine, and when I look at the edit history of the answer, there was never any other screenshot there, so user2453382's comment doesn't seem to make any sense. The link to imgur.com/IGLud.jpg was there before their comment.

Answer (score 6):

`R.java` is the generated file by ADT or Android studio. It will be located under `app\build\generated\source\r` directory.

```
./app/build/generated/source/r/debug/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.java
./app/build/generated/source/r/debug/your/packagename/name/R.java
```

Comment: there is no directory called r under source. see other answers - the source is no longer generated, only bytecode, if your AGP version is 3.6 or above.

Answer (score 5):

1. In my project in Android Studio 4.1
   [image]
2. R.jar that you can actually unzip resides in app build folder, as follows:

   jar -xf R.jar

[image]

3. Once the jar is unpacked you can find R.java inside of app package:
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

I am using Android Studio 2.2.3 , the R.java file is shown in the picture below.
Goto in the left upper side there is a selecting list ,

1. select [package]
2. Open "App Folder"
3. com.example.saeedanwar.myapplication;
4. r

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Mac or Linux, try the following command line on your terminal:

```sh
find . -name "R.*"
```

It will print something like:

```
./app/build/intermediaries/runtime_symbol_list/debug/R.txt
./app/build/intermediaries/compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar/debug/R.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

It is inside `app\build\generated\source\r` folder

Answer (score 1):

This answer will be in a constant state of flux until Android standardize a method of matching their *annoying* decimal/hexadecimal *id* references to a tangible resource such as *my_layout.xml*.

For Android Studio **Dolphin** | 2021.3.1 Patch 1 have a look at this file:

```
/project/package/build/intermediates/stable_resource_ids_file/debug/stableIds.txt
```

It is produced by RUN (not just BUILD). Sample:

```
layout/mtrl_picker_header_fullscreen = 0x7f0d00de
string/cancel = 0x7f1101f0
style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar = 0x7f1202f3
id/gpxBtn = 0x7f0a0346
```

Answer (score 0):

Project/app/build/generated/source/r/debug/com.android.'projectname'/R.java

Answer (score 0):

--The R.Java that contains your xml layouts and views id's in Android Studio 3.5.3 -- Project/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/r/com/"your package"/R.java

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the AGP generates `R.class` files directly and there's no `R.java`  out-of-the-box. But we can decompile the class files to get a glimpse of `R.java`'s former structure. Note that this method won't show the actual resource IDs, but some of the other answers cover that bit. The steps below are tested on `Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1`.

1. Locate `R.jar` (there may also be a `release` folder):

[image: R.jar]

2. Right-click the file (or the `debug` folder) and from the pop-up menu choose `Open In -> Terminal`.
3. Execute, from the terminal, `jar -xf R.jar` to extract the folders into cwd, which will give you something like this:

[image: R.class]

4. Double-click the `R` class above and it will open in the editor as decompiled code.
5. (Optional) remove the newly extracted folders because they will become obsolete when you continue working on the project.