# How to find the R file in Android Studio 2020?

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.6

I've search on here how to do it but I found sources from 2015 and the layout of Android Studio has changed since then. Where is the R file in Android Studio.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvZGj.png)

Comment: Since there have been many Android Studio versions published so far in 2020... what version are you using?

Comment: Android Studio 3.6.3

Comment: It does not always seem to be generated in source form. I do not know the rules for which modules do and do not have `R.java` generated (other than it is not tied to whether Kotlin is involved). I assume it is related to some specific Gradle settings. If it *is* generated, I am seeing it in the module's` `build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r/your/application/id/R.java`, where `your/application/id/` would be directories based on your application ID.

Answer (score 12):

According to the [**docs**](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#simplified-r-class); for improving the efficiency and build performance of gradle; the plugin now generates the **JAR** directly instead of generating intermediate `R.java` files. In previous gradle plugins; `R.java` would be generated for all the dependencies which you include in your `app.gradle` file or external dependencies. These R classes were then compiled alongside the app's other java classes; which would create overheads and unnecessary or redundant compilations thereby slowing down the build performances of the application.

> The Android Gradle plugin simplifies the compile classpath by generating only one R class for each library module in your project and sharing those R classes with other module dependencies.

The new optimization that is done may improve build performance for projects with many dependencies significantly, and improve the indexing speed also thus requiring faster and efficient builds in android studio.

When I tried to decompile the `R jar` file which is located at `your_project_directory\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug` using **jd-gui**; I was able to get the `R.class` implementation containing id's of the `Views` which I used for my application just like we would get in earlier versions of gradle.(which confirmed the linking.)[image]

**NOTE:**

If your application is using **AAPT2**; then you can generate the `R.java` and Proguard rules intermediate files. To get the command syntax; you can use [**options**](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2#link) from `aapt2 link` command.

Answer (score 5):

The new Android Gradle Plugin generates the corresponding bytecode directly and does not make the intermediate R.java file.

> Source

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/android-studio-36.html

[image]

Comment: But sometimes it still does generate `R.java`, as I noted in a comment on the question.

Answer (score 3):

It is present at the location :

**ProjectName**\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug

In the above directory as R.jar

[image]

Comment: i am having the namespace error. whenever i create android library i find namespace error which lead me to this error.  how can i solve namespace error.

Answer (score 1):

See [Where is the R.java file in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522144/where-is-the-r-java-file-in-android-studio).

1. Turn to `Project` view and find `app/outputs/apk/debug/app-name-debug.apk`.

[image]

2. Find your package name among `classes*.dex` files.

[image]

3. Expand the package and find `R$id` (see picture 1).
4. Right-click and press `Show Bytecode`.
5. You will see a file where you can find needed id. Click inside the file, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and paste id.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

R is Generated class in android and after you build your project this class will be create
first build your project after that 4 times click on shift button on your keyboard.
in new windows search 'R' class and in list find R.java class
that's it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdC0d.png

Comment: Your screenshot is showing the platform implementation of `R`, not a project's generated `R`. Your answer also does not show where the generated `R.java` would be on the filesystem, and your answer does not explain the rules by which `R.java` is or is not generated.