# where to find r.java in android studio in latest version

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm reading a book in that book they say I can find R.java file in some sort of path but I go thought the path they said I can't find the file and I think in latest version of android studio looks like they changed it , so now where I can find the r.java file

Comment: GUYS answer for this questions , you can find in the given link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719632/how-to-find-the-r-file-in-android-studio-2020

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The R file is a generated class. The easiest way to find it is opening any activity you like say the `MainActivity` which comes in by default

You will have something like this in the `onCreate` function

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main):

}
```

In this method you can find the `R` class. To know what's actually inside it you can hover your mouse pointer over the R and then Ctrl + Click( Win, Linux) or Cmd + Click (mac) it to get to the definition

Comment: It's not working I already tried it , Any other options

Comment: @Youtheone: did you build your project at least once before trying this?