# Where is R.java file located in android studio 4.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[Screenshot here -> Not found r folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pf2y.png) I can not find **R.java file** in android studio still it works fine.
When I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on **R** in (R.id.gridLayout) does nothing. so where I can find this file. **Android Studio v4.2.1**

Comment: rebuild your project there must be some error in your layout xml file which cause `R.java` to not generate.

Comment: still not find @ADM

Comment: I think this answer will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61079734/191761

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem following the Udemy course "Learn Android Application Development." I found the following while looking for an answer:
[R.java file is missing/not generated in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63369367/r-java-file-is-missing-not-generated-in-android-studio)

Answer (score -3):

Change the view of your project from Android to Package mode. Then Open app folder then build, then generated folder, then source folder and then you will find r folder, then you will find your package name, click on that folder you will find R.java file there.

[image: Like in this Image]

Comment: please check the image I attached recently

Comment: The image shows android studio 2.1 NOT android studio version 4. Your answer is useless