# I can't find the R-File In Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: R-File isn't found]
Can someone please help me find the R-file? I cleaned and rebuilt my project yet i still couldn't find it

Comment: check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522144/where-is-the-r-java-file-in-android-studio

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

ProjectName > app> build > intermediates > local_only_symbol_list > debug > R-def.txt